# Problems with gem install

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I am trying to install the activerecord gem for ruby on my (unfortunately) Windows 8 machine.  I just installed DevKit and have tried running the following in PowerShell

```
gem install activerecord
```

and this is the output I get

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 directory.
```

I am an administrator on the machine so I cannot for the life of me figure out what it doesn't like.

Comment: Are you opening the powershell as an admin? I have not used win8 but that is what i have to do on my Win 7 machine sometimes.

Comment: @AbhishekAsthana I've tried that and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Does every directory exist in this chain? C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1

Comment: @vgoff Yup.  I've even added my user with full permissions on all of them.

Comment: Try adding ruby first -> rvm use 1.9.3 --install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to uninstall and reinstall Ruby and DevKit to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you haven't done this, when you set the permissions on the C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 directory did you tell it to propagate downward? If you go into Properties -> Advanced on the Ruby193 directory and choose "replace all child object permissions...." you might get a different result. That or find the binary for the gem command and make sure it runs as admin by default, so anything it spawns is also running as admin.Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, you said you used Powershell, have you tried it in a plain .cmd window?

Comment: Hmmm... tried it with both on a Win 8 VM on my Mac and both worked no problem.